# call a function inside a module in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I may be confusing OO with JS modules but I want to do something like this:

```
export default {
    functionA:()=>{
        this.functionB
    },
    functionB:()=>{
        console.log('Hello from functionB')
    },
}
```

then:

```
import pc from 'path/to/pc'

pc.functionA
```

desired result: `'Hello from functionB'`

actual result: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'functionB' of undefined`

What is the correct way to do this?? Is it even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: haha, just scrolled up lol

Comment: I struggle to understand how that answers my question, my question is about exporting modules, not about how to use arrow functions...

Comment: Ah ok, I understand, because the arrow function does not scope this the same thats why i get my problem, i changed to regular functions and all good. Thanks mate.